# Progress bar based on file download

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, download, node-webkit

How would I display a progress bar based on file downloaded in node webkit?

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var file = fs.createWriteStream("update_setup.exe");
var len = 0; 
var request = https.get(url + 'appdata/update_setup.exe', function (response) {
  response.pipe(file);
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    file.write(chunk);
    len += chunk.length;
    var percent = (len / response.headers['content-length']) * 100;
  });
  file.on('finish', function () {
    setTimeout(function () { win.close(); exec('update_setup.exe'); }, 1000);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the `content-length` header of the response and compare it to the amount of bytes that have already been downloaded.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var file = fs.createWriteStream('dest');
var len = 0;

http.get(url, function(res) {
  res.on('data', function(chunk) {
    file.write(chunk);
    len += chunk.length;

    // percentage downloaded is as follows
    var percent = (len / res.headers['content-length']) * 100;
  });
  res.on('end', function() {
    file.close();
  });
  file.on('close', function() {
    // the file is done downloading
    exec('update_setup.exe');
  });
});
```

This code checks the length of the data received and adds it to `len`. Divide `len` by the file's total size and multiply by a hundred to get a percentage.

Comment: When I try to run this code, the file downloads, but is twice the size it should be, and Windows says it is not a valid application.

Comment: Get rid of `res.pipe()` and change `file.on('finish', function() {});` to `res.on('end', function() {});`. The `file.write()` is a replacement for `res.pipe()` but allows us to how large each chunk of data is.

Comment: OK, I've made those changes, the file is downloaded correctly, but now the file will not open on end.

Comment: Actually, use `file.on('close', function() {});` since the file is not guaranteed to be finished writing when the response stream ends.

Comment: Still not executing the file unfortunately

Comment: I've edited the example. Now when the stream closes, a handler will close the file's writable stream as well.

Comment: check `Content-Encoding` header - it might be gzipped

Comment: That is a good point, although the code did work when it was just `res.pipe(file);`.

Comment: Ok that works now! Thank-you. Would I just point a progress bar's value at the percent variable? Such as $('.progress').val = percent;?

Comment: Yes, the percent variable is the file download progress.