# progress bar while opening pdf using fpdf

Tags: javascript

I am generating a lot of pdf reports using `fpdf` class. While opening pdf a 'loading....' image (using cookies along with an animated .gif) is working on the page and it disappears once the pdf file is fully opened (it is opened as pdf document outside the browser by setting the browser option 'always ask').

Now what I need is a **percentage progress bar** using javascript/jquery   while the pdf document is buffering or opening in. Is this possible?
This is useful because some of my pdf reports take a lot of time to open.

Comment: There are a couple of other threads about this .. fexample: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19286529/progress-bar-based-on-file-download

Answer (score 0):

yes it's possible. the question then is how you'd get the server to notify the client on what percentage it's on. that's a bit more complex. web-sockets would be optimal but the most difficult to implement.. an easier way would be to get the client to poll the server (say every 1s) during the pdf generation to ask it what percentage it's on.

here's the client code though to get you started.

```js
// using jquery 
$('#bar').animate({width: '35%'});
```

```css
#barContainer {
  width:300px;
  height:15px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}

#bar {
  height:100%;
  width:0%;
  background:#0198E1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='barContainer'>
  <div id='bar'></div>
</div>
```