# Telling Apache server that my page is busy working on fpdf generation and not hung

Tags: php, apache, fpdf

I use `fpdf` to create a `pdf` document using php. It works but sometimes it can take a long time to produce the finished report and if the time takes over 60 seconds I get the **500 Internal Server Error**.

I have spoken my service provider and they have told me that this setting cannot be overridden programatically (such as max_execution_time) and that I need to keep their server aware that the page is still running. They said that a good way to do that is to have progress bar but unfamiliar with `fpdf`.

This would be a great additional feature as well as solving the problem, however `fpdf` does not allow any output client side as it will give the error

> FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

So my question is either,

Is there any way you  a progress bar can be displayed while an fpdf is being generated? (I have looked at this question [progress bar while opening pdf using fpdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35194888/progress-bar-while-opening-pdf-using-fpdf) but it doesn't seem to address the 'data already outputted' error)

or

If this is not possible is there a way for 'talking' to the Apache server during the process of generating the pdf to let it know the page is still busy working on it?

Comment: You need to keep each individual HTTP request and response as short as possible. If you have a long-running job, it should run on a background process, not the main web server process. The HTTP request should initiate the background process and then return a "please wait" website, which can refresh every once in a while to check on the progress. That means you need a system where you can run PHP in a way other than just through Apache; e.g. a queue-worker system like Gearman, ØMQ, or at least cron jobs. Describing all that in detail is a bit too broad to a single answer here.

Comment: Thanks - I will look into this. Are you saying however there is no way of getting the server to know the page is still busy? Won't getting it to work in the background continue to have the same effect with the 'busy' page still taking a long time to complete?

Comment: Apache *knows* PHP is still busy doing something, Apache is the executing container process. The thing is, Apache does *want* to let PHP work forever, because that's not what a web process should ever do, and it's a protection against buggy scripts which may "stay busy" forever and would kill the server. Your goal should be to return any HTTP request within ~200ms or sooner; anything that takes longer does not belong into a web server process.